# Getting working directory on OpenFileDialog

Tags: winapi, openfiledialog

When you select a number of files on OpenFileDialog you get the working directory path in a structure member of  `OPENFILENAME` but when you select a single file you get the path to filename in that variable member.

Would there be a possible way to get the path first before looping and counting to check the number of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, OpenFileDialog is a .NET class.  Assuming native: you can set the OPENFILENAME.lpfnHook member to a callback function.  That gives you notifications like CDN_FILEOK and CDN_FOLDERCHANGE.  Gives you a preview of what was selected before the dialog closes and a way to cancel it.

Comment: Yes, CDN_FOLDERCHANGE is what i needed so then CDM_GETFOLDERPATH can get the path to current working directory.